# Android: open Browser and come back after back

Tags: android, android-intent, browser

i am starting the browser with

```
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
i.setData(Uri.parse(url));
startActivity(i);
```

and want to come back to my activity after pressing back.

how i do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use a VebView to run browser in your application like this:

> Layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
style="@style/my_style" >

<WebView
    android:id="@+id/myWebView"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_below="@id/help_tabbar" />
```

> Java code

```
WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.myWebView);
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

    final Activity activity = this;
    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        /**
         * open page inside tabbar activity
         */
        public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode,
                String description, String failingUrl) {
            Toast.makeText(activity, description, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .show();
        }
    });
    webView.loadUrl(getString(R.string.my_url));
}
```

And if you want to open in external browser you can use this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
                Uri.parse(getString(R.string.my_url)));
        startActivity(intent);
```

Always keep your url into string because it's easy to modify.
Hope this is usefull.
Cheers

Comment: webview is an option, and the second possiblity is almost the same as my code, isnt it possible to open the external browser and let the activity stay in backstack?

Comment: It is difficult because you or any user maybe have 100 apps running in the same time. My opinion is to make a webview, it is much easyer for any user to stay in app and search a webpage, then put app in bg, open browser, close browser, restore app --- as you see there are 4 steps that a user should make just for a simple webpage, insted he can make just 1.